# Dealing with html table in xsl

Tags: html, xml, xslt, html-table

I'm trying to create an html table via xsl. I can't seem to work out a better way for the following structure for my [table](http://jsfiddle.net/JTpme/). 
The problem is the "2ColumnHeader" with subtitles. 
How would I need to setup my table structure and also the

```
<xsl:for-each>
```

loop?

Right now it's just:

```
<tr> <td> <xsl:value-of select="@xyz" /> </td> .......</tr>
```

I hope that was a clear description of my problem.

UPDATE:

So here is my cleaned-up xsl-table with random data:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>No.:</th>
        <th>Heading1</th>
        <th>Heading2</th>
        <th>Heading3</th>
        <th>Heading4</th>
        <th>I need two subheadings for this Heading</th> 
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>       

<xsl:for-each select="tabledata">
   <tr>
        <td><xsl:number/></td>
        <td> <xsl:value-of select="@name" /> </td>
        <td> <xsl:value-of select="description" /> </td>
        <td> <xsl:value-of select="text1" /> </td>
        <td> <xsl:value-of select="text2" /> </td>
        <td> <xsl:value-of select="text3" /> </td>
```

```
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
 </tbody>       
</table>
```

Comment: *"I hope that was a clear description of my problem"* - Without seeing your current XSLT code and XML? No.

Comment: It's good that you've shown the HTML output you need, but we can't do anything unless we can see the source XML that you want to transform. You also probably don't need an `<xsl:for-each>` element. That is procedural thinking.